# How to make main menu behave as "Wordpress Menu"?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, menu

I have a problem with my menu. I want to make it so that it behave like the "Wordpress Admin Menu". As you can see in Wordpress menu when you scroll the Wordpress page both the menu and content side scroll at same time but when the option of menu finished scrolling it gets stacked at that position and the rest of the page keeps scrolling. I want the same behavior in menu. You can see in [this video](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/37703778/semi%20fixed%20left%20navigation%20bar.mp4) how it behaves.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tie `scrollTop`of the `oneElement` to `scrollTop`of the `otherElement`.
You can achieve this with `jQuery`:

```
$( 'oneElement' ).scroll( function() {
    $( 'otherElement' ).scrollTop( $( this ).scrollTop() );    
});
```

So if you scroll `oneElement`, `otherElement` is scrolled too.

See it working on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/daB0bby/Lz833xpp/2/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: can you please show me the example on jsfiddle. it will be nice of you. because i am not able to figure it out.

Comment: Here you go. Added `JSFiddle` link to my answer.